# Obtaining data bound to dom elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently learning data visualizations with d3.js. I am using the tutorial on the d3.js site. I am at the part where the data bound to DOM elements have to retrieved. I did it exactly as they have shown, but I am not able to get the data from it.
Here is the code from the beginning:

```
var theData=[1,2,3]
var p= d3.select("body")
.selectAll("p")
.data(theData)
.enter()
.append("p")
.text("hello")
```

This displays:

hello
hello
hello

Now, on the site, it tells me to enter the following code to obtain the data bound i.e. 1,2 & 3.

```
var theData=[1,2,3]
var p= d3.select("body")
.selectAll("p")
.data(theData)
.enter()
.append("p")
.text(function (d) { return d; } )
```

Even after doing this, the page does not change,like it should to:

1
2
3

It remains the same(it keeps showing the three hello's).

How do I get the data back?

Comment: are you able to put it in a JSFiddle so we can alter the code ?

Comment: here @AJ_91 https://jsfiddle.net/mayukh/cwqwbw3u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when just using this :

```
var theData2 = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

var p2 = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
  .data(theData2)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text( function (d) { 
      console.log(d);
      return d; } );
```

It works, you're using variables with the same names which you really shouldn't do

http://jsfiddle.net/cwqwbw3u/1/

Comment: another way ; http://jsfiddle.net/cwqwbw3u/2/. I dont get why you writing 'theData' out twice, and using 'var p' twice either :/ Anyway, i believe ive solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code, it works (however, I am a all for pretty javascript, so I added ';' when approriate).

I would suggest checking out the console on the browsers developers tools (perhaps there are showing errors already) and change your code to something like this:

```
var theData=[1,2,3];

var p= d3.select("body")
.selectAll("p")
.data(theData)
.enter()
.append("p")
.text(function (d) { 
    console.log("checking d");
    console.log(d);
    return d; 
} );
```

it would be really weird if you did not see at least "checking d" in your console...

Answer (score 0):

When our dataset contains more items than available DOM elements, the surplus data items are stored in a sub set of this selection called the enter selection. When you try to use `enter` for the second time, there are already 3 elements and so no items are stored in enter selection. You should have used the same enter selection for both tasks.

```js
var theData=[1,2,3]
var p = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("p")
  .data(theData);

p.enter()
  .append("p")
  .text("hello");

p.enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function (d) { return d; } );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```